# Is this operator bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $w_j$ be a basis ( not orthogonal) of the Hilbert space $H$. For $h = \sum^\infty a_iw_i$ define $P_n(h) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iw_i$. Is this operator bounded in $H$

I don't think it is but I feel like it should be.

Comment: By basis, you mean that the linear span of the $w_j$ is dense in $H$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. If by "basis", you mean every element in $H$ has a unique representation $\sum\alpha_i w_i$. This is a standard result that holds in Banach spaces. In fact, the operators $(P_n)$ are uniformly bounded. A proof can be found in Kalton and Albiac's *Topics in Banach Space Theory*. See Theorem 1.1.3 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false). (I'm not sure if the result is easier to prove for Hilbert Spaces.)

Comment: @DavideGiraudo yes that's what I mean

Comment: @DavidMitra thanks I will have a look for that book